# java script how to convert a string to number array

Tags: javascript, arrays, type-conversion, nan

I have a string named :

```
graph_data =[16.665,0,16.665,19.23,35.79,16.665,31.71,16.665,0,16.665,0,16.665,16.665,41.615]
```

I wanted to covert it to array of number. I am using the following code:

```
var graph_data1=new Array();
var graph_data = graph_data.split(",");
for (var i=0; i<graph_data.length; i++)
{
graph_data1[i] = parseFloat(graph_data[i]);
}
```

the output of `graph_data1` is showing following  `NaN,0,16.665,19.23,35.79,16.665,31.71,16.665,0,16.665,0,16.665,16.665,41.615`

can any one tell me why it is adding `Nan` and `0`

thanks in advance .

Comment: if your string is indeed a string, the first element after split would be `[16.665` which is NaN ... your second element is `0`, which is why you get a `0`

Comment: Check [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/agq8q1jL/)

Comment: Does your string actually contain `graph_data=`?

Answer (score 7):

You could do this quite easily with JSON.parse

```
var myArray = JSON.parse('[16.665, 0, 16.665, 19.23, 35.79, 16.665, 31.71, 16.665, 0, 16.665, 0, 16.665, 16.665, 41.615]')
```

and if you want to do it all at one shot a replace to remove the content before [

```
var myArray = JSON.parse('graph_data = [16.665, 0, 16.665, 19.23, 35.79, 16.665, 31.71, 16.665, 0, 16.665, 0, 16.665, 16.665, 41.615]'.replace(/.*\[/,'['))
```

Comment: Not if the string begins with `graph_data =` you couldn't.

Comment: good point! A substring or replace should fix that. editing in a bit.

Comment: damn, way faster than me :<

Comment: Little annoyed with myself that I didn't think of this, my substring answer below is looking a little stupid right now :)

Answer (score 0):

Issue is that your code is trying to parse the "[" character as a number use substring to get around this like below:

```
var graph_data="[16.665,0,16.665,19.23,35.79,16.665,31.71,16.665,0,16.665,0,16.665,16.665,41.615]";
var graph_data1=[];
var graph_data = graph_data.substring(1, graph_data.length - 2).split(",");
for (var i=0; i<graph_data.length; i++)
{
graph_data1[i] = parseFloat(graph_data[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using

```
graph_data.split(',');
```

it is taking the first number as

```
[16.665
```

you need to remove [ from your number
you can do that by simply doing

```
graph_data1[i] = parseFloat(graph_data[i].replace('[',''));
```

although this is not good practice but it will do the job for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.parse` instead

```
graph_data  ="[16.665,0,16.665,19.23,35.79,16.665,31.71,16.665,0,16.665,0,16.665,16.665,41.615]"

graph_data = JSON.parse(graph_data)

console.log(graph_data)
=> [16.665, 0, 16.665, 19.23, 35.79, 16.665, 31.71, 16.665, 0, 16.665, 0, 16.665, 16.665, 41.615]
```

Answer (score 0):

Much easier, just json parse from the start to the end of the array:

```
var myString = "graph_data =[16.665,0,16.665,19.23,35.79,16.665,31.71,16.665,0,16.665,0,16.665,16.665,41.615]";
var startInd = myString.indexOf('[');
var endInd = myString.indexOf(']')+1; //+1 to include the ]
var myIntArr = JSON.parse(myString.substring(startInd, endInd));
console.log(myIntArr) // [16.665,0,16.665,19.23,35.79,...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

```
graph_data='[16.665,0,16.665,19.23,35.79,16.665,31.71,16.665,0,16.665,0,16.665,16.665,41.615]'
var regexp = /(\+|-)?((\d+(\.\d+)?)|(\.\d+))/gi;
var matches_array = graph_data.match(regexp);
graph_data_array = matches_array.map(function (t) {
        return t;
    });
console.log(graph_data_array)
```